# Why isn't a data.table sorted properly after calling setDT?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, data.table

When a data table is turned into a data frame and then back into a data table it may keep the sorted attribute even though it is not sorted (see the example below). This leads to incorrect results when merging data.tables, and possible undetected bugs. 
Is this the expected behavior? What is the best way to turn a data.frame into a sorted data.table and verify that it is indeed sorted?

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

a <- data.table(id = c('a', 'B', 'c'), value = c(1,2,3))
b <- data.table(id = c('a', 'B', 'c'))

setkey(a,id)
a_sum <- a %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarize_at(vars(value), sum) 
setDT(a_sum, key = "id")

a_sum_nokey = setkey(copy(a_sum), NULL)
merged_key_fails = merge(a_sum, b, by="id")
merged_no_key_works = merge(a_sum_nokey, b, by="id")
```

Comment: Did you mean `setDT(a_sum, key="id")`? - `keep.rownames=` is the second argument to `setDT`, not `key=`

Comment: Yes, I just fixed the code, thank you

Comment: So that should solve the issue now I think? `merged_key_fails` and `merged_no_key_works` are identical now after this minor correction.

Comment: I just ran the code in a clean R session and merge_key_fails and merged_no_key_works returned different results.  merge_key_fails did not include the 'a' row. Maybe I'm missing the correction?